# an "algebraic relation" by any other name...?

Tags: complex-analysis, terminology, relations

I am confronted with this definition which is unfamiliar to me:

> Suppose $F\subset \mathbb C\times \mathbb C$ is a relation. $F$ is said to be **algebraic** if there exists a matrix $A\in M_{n+1}(\mathbb C)$ such that no row of $A$ is the zero vector, and
>
> $$(x,y)\in F\iff \sum_{p=1}^{n+1}\sum_{q=1}^{n+1}A_{pq}y^{p-1}x^{q-1}=0$$

I'd like to find out more about it. I've been trying to find this in other texts without much luck, and hampered by the obvious problem of only having "algebraic relation" as a search term.

This appeared in the context of a text on analytic functions, at the end of a chapter about analytic relations, analytic continuation, and branch-points.

---

It might be useful to provide the remaining context provided by the book (there isn't much!) The definition above is only used for three following exercises, and the book does not go any further into this thing. The exercises are:

1. If $F$ is an algebraic relation, show $F^{-1}$ is algebraic also.
2. If $g$ is an analytic function and $g\subseteq F$, then $F$ contains every analytic relation extending $g$.
3. If $G$ is an analytic relation contained in an algebraic relation, then $G'$ (the derivative of $G$) is also contained in an algebraic relation.

That's it... I think that's all that is mentioned.

---

Can someone point me to other texts where this idea appears and/or give other terminology that might lead me to see more about this?

Comment: It just means the graph of the relation is an algebraic curve. I'm not sure what you want to know but you can try looking in textbooks on algebraic geometry for information about plane algebraic curves.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Well, *yes*, I have heard of algebraic curves, but the restriction in the definition must mean something. If this had been $\mathbb R$ instead of $\mathbb C$, then $x^2+y^2 - 1 = 0$ doesn't fit the definition given above. So it might not be as simplistic as you assumed. And I would imagine this matrix has a name? The only matrix mentioned at the algebraic curve wiki, for example, is the Jacobian, and it looks like it's not square as described there. Can you tell me if you know the terms for this restriction and/or the matrix? Thanks.

Comment: I think you really should not think of $A_{pq}$ as a matrix. It's just a way of listing all the coefficients of a polynomial. I can't make any sense of the row condition, which I initially thought was just some straightforward nondegeneracy condition but now I just have no idea why anyone would want it. Do you see it used somewhere in the text?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I agree the description is a little peculiar. The definition appears at the end of the last chapter of the book, and is followed by three exercises that use the definition, although I don't immediately see use of the nondegeneracy condition. The book includes many "jumping off points to different fields" and this is apparently one of them. Maybe I should include the exercises in the post above as clues...

Comment: Exercise 1 seems false to me. Taking the inverse relation has the effect of transposing the coefficients, so the condition that no row is zero becomes the condition that no column is zero. I remain confused...

Comment: @QiaochuYuan  same here... and that's pat of the reason I'm asking if anyone thinks it looks familiar.

Comment: I'm also coming to suspect that it was intended that just *there exists* a row that is nonzero, rather than *each* row is nonzero.  If that's the case, then maybe it really is just an algebraic curve.